# Why rabbitmq lost messages?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I first use send.rb to send 100 messages to rabbitmq, then use `rabbitmqctl list_queues` to see status, and it is 100 messages in queue. Then I start recv.rb to recv message, and I actually get 100 messages.

Then, I start recv.rb first, then use send.rb to send 100 messages, finally I only can get 95 messages. I tried many times, and I never get 100 messages in this situaltion .

Why I am lost messages?

**recv.rb**

```
require 'amqp'

AMQP.start(:host => '127.0.0.1') do |connection|
  channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  queue   = channel.queue("test_queue", :durable => true)

  Signal.trap("INT") do
    connection.close do
      EM.stop { exit }
    end
  end

  channel.prefetch(1)

  queue.subscribe(:ack => true) do |header, body|
    puts body
    header.ack  # A 
  end
end
```

If I replace `# A` line into

```
    EM.add_timer(body.count(".")) do
      puts " [x] Done"
      header.ack
    end
```

the same as rabbitmq-tutorials, this script crashes:

```
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/amq-client-0.9.10/lib/amq/client/async/adapter.rb:247:in `send_frame': Trying to send frame through a closed connection. Frame is #<AMQ::Protocol::MethodFrame:0x000000019dc6e0 @payload="\x00<\x00P\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00", @channel=2> (AMQ::Client::ConnectionClosedError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/amq-client-0.9.10/lib/amq/client/async/channel.rb:138:in `acknowledge'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/amqp-0.9.8/lib/amqp/channel.rb:1003:in `acknowledge'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/amqp-0.9.8/lib/amqp/header.rb:35:in `ack'
    from recv.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/amqp-0.9.8/lib/amqp/connection.rb:38:in `start'
    from recv.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you post your send.rb as well?  It's hard to diagnose this seeing only one side of the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you are trying to publish over a connection that has been closed. Please post the script you use for publishing and any recent messages you have in the RabbitMQ log.